# Connecting Raspberry Pi to Unity via Bluetooth

Tags: unity-game-engine, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, connection

I want to connect my Raspberry Pi to unity via Bluetooth (I am writing an app that in the future will use the phone to connect to the Pi via Bluetooth).

How do I do that ? I was not able to find the answer on SO or anywhere else.

How do I transfer data via Bluetooth ?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I do that ? I was not able to find the answer on SO or anywhere else.

I googled it and found [this](http://nerdclub-uk.blogspot.com/2017/03/bluetooth-with-unity-for-ios-and-android.html)

> How do I transfer data via Bluetooth ?

This might help [link](https://www.electronicwings.com/raspberry-pi/using-raspberry-pi-3-on-board-bluetooth-for-communication)

Or you could write a python script similar to this

```
# Uses Bluez for Linux
#
# sudo apt-get install bluez python-bluez
# 
# Taken from: https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x232.html
# Taken from: https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c212.html

import bluetooth

def receiveMessages():
  server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

  port = 1
  server_sock.bind(("",port))
  server_sock.listen(1)

  client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
  print "Accepted connection from " + str(address)

  while True:
    data = client_sock.recv(1024)
    print "received [%s]" % data

  #client_sock.close()
  #server_sock.close()

def sendMessageTo(targetBluetoothMacAddress):
  port = 1
  sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
  sock.connect((targetBluetoothMacAddress, port))
  sock.send("hello!!")
  sock.close()

def lookUpNearbyBluetoothDevices():
  nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
  for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
    print str(bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr )) + " [" + str(bdaddr) + "]"


lookUpNearbyBluetoothDevices()
receiveMessages()
```

**Code Description:** It looks up for available Bluetooth devices and receives messages from the first Bluetooth device which initiates the connection. It sends messages to target Bluetooth device as per mac address specified in function arguments.

**Reference:** [Link](https://gist.github.com/keithweaver/3d5dbf38074cee4250c7d9807510c7c3)